# LDAP communication between two local server

Tags: ubuntu, ldap, port, openldap

I want to make my LDAP Port accessible inside my private network. Is it possible?

Operating System : Ubuntu 14.04 x64

My LDPA Server configuration:

```
eth1  Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 04:01:41:0d:9d:02  
      inet addr:**10.129.129.244**  Bcast:10.129.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::601:41ff:fe0d:9d02/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:3395 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:3358 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:203936 (203.9 KB)  TX bytes:181780 (181.7 KB)
```

Netstat result:

```
netstat -anltp | grep "LISTEN" | grep 389
tcp        0      0 **127.0.1.1:389**           0.0.0.0:*  LISTEN 1096/slapd
```

And another server (i want to use as a ldap client for authentication purposes.)

Operating System: Ubuntu 14.10 x64

```
eth1  Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 04:01:41:71:8d:02  
      inet addr:10.129.129.243  Bcast:10.129.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::601:41ff:fe71:8d02/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:2192 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:2226 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:131520 (131.5 KB)  TX bytes:129152 (129.1 KB)
```

NMAP results:

```
nmap 10.129.129.244

Starting Nmap 6.46 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2015-03-02 07:44 EST
Nmap scan report for 10.129.129.244
Host is up (0.00054s latency).
Not shown: 989 closed ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
22/tcp   open  ssh
25/tcp   open  smtp
110/tcp  open  pop3
143/tcp  open  imap
443/tcp  open  https
465/tcp  open  smtps
587/tcp  open  submission
993/tcp  open  imaps
995/tcp  open  pop3s
7025/tcp open  vmsvc-2
8443/tcp open  https-alt
MAC Address: 04:01:41:0D:9D:02 (Unknown)

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 21.45 seconds
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to make my LDAP Port accessible inside my private network. Is it possible?

**Yes.**

You'll need to resolve the fact that your LDAP server only listens at the loopback interface as indicated by the netstat output: `tcp        0      0 **127.0.1.1:389**           0.0.0.0:*  LISTEN 1096/slapd` and make it accept remote connections as well. Possibly you need to open a firewall as well to allow remote connections.

In general if you're going to use LDAP for authentication you should consider configuring SSL/TLS as well to provide transit [security](http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/security.html).

Comment: Thanks. Is there anyway to  make it accept remote connections as well ?

Comment: @aymeba: The [security](http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/security.html) link I included explains how to restrict OpenLDAP 2.4 to a single interface, which seems like how you configured your server, and explains that if you don't, OpenLDAP will listen to all interfaces, which sounds like what you want.

Comment: I'm using zimbra collab. on my server and the problem is that i can not execute slapd command.

Comment: Solved. Commented line in etc/hosts:

# 127.0.1.1 domain.com sample.com